# Print a layered cake

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

### Challenge

Given an input `n`, print an ASCII art cake `n` layers tall, viewed from the side, with two candles on top. Refer to the examples below for details.

### Output

```
>> cake(1)

 _|_|_
|     |
+-----+

>> cake(3)

     _|_|_
    |     |
  +---------+
  |         |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
```

...and so on.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes prohibited
- Please make an attempt at a clever solution
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins. However, the answer will not be selected.

### Have fun!

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 238 chars

```
i=input()
m=["+"+"-"*(i*4+1)+"+","|"+" "*(i*4+1)+"|"]
for v in range(i,1,-1):
 m+=[" "*(i-v)*2+"+"+"-"*(v*4+1)+"+"," "*(i-v+1)*2+"|"+" "*((v-1)*4+1)+"|"]
m.pop()
m+=[" "*(i-1)*2+"|"+" "*5+"|"," "*(i-1)*2+" _|_|_"]
print'\n'.join(m[::-1])
```

The missing example of Cake 2:

```
   _|_|_
  |     |
+---------+
|         |
+---------+
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! You could take input from STDIN and take off 24 chars. For example, `i=int(input())`

Comment: If you want, you should be able to change to Python 2 and change `int(input())` to `input()` and the `print` statement, plus you can change the four spaces to one (if it's a tab, change it to a space to make it more obvious that it's one character). Plus your bytecount is 4 too high for some reason.

Comment: @Mars Ultor oops, yes, I'm not sure why I chose python 3 to begin with. Thanks.

Comment: You may also be able to save a few bytes using percent formatting

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <strike>109</strike> 107 bytes

```
->n{p=->t{puts t.center 3+4*n}
p['_|_|_']
(1..n).map{|i|p[?|+' '*(1+4*i)+?|]
p[?++?-*((i<n ?5:1)+4*i)+?+]}}
```

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 134 bytes

A recursive cake.

```javascript
f=(n,i=--n,r=(n,c)=>'- '[+!c].repeat(n),p=r((i-n)*2),j=n*4+5,x=p+`+${r(j,1)}+
`)=>(n?f(n-1,i)+x:p+` _|_|_
`)+p+`|${r(j)}|
`+(n-i?'':x)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f=(n,i=--n,r=(n,c)=>'- '[+!c].repeat(n),p=r((i-n)*2),j=n*4+5,x=p+`+${r(j,1)}+
`)=>(n?f(n-1,i)+x:p+` _|_|_
`)+p+`|${r(j)}|
`+(n-i?'':x)

console.log(f(4))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 233 bytes

```
@echo off
set i=
for /l %%j in (2,1,%1)do call set i=  %%i%%
echo %i% _^|_^|_
set s=-----
for /l %%j in (2,1,%1)do call:l
echo ^|%s:-= %^|
echo +%s%+
exit/b
:l
echo %i%^|%s:-= %^|
set i=%i:~2%
set s=----%s%
echo %i%+%s%+
```

Shorter than Python? Something must be wrong...

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 103 bytes

```hs
f(a:b)n=a:([0..4*n]>>b)++[a]
x!n=x:[f"| "n,f"+-"n]
g 1=" _|_|_"!1
g n=map("  "++)(init.g$n-1)++f"+-"n!n
```

Defines a function `g` which returns a list of strings containing the lines of the output

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, <s>115</s>, 101 chars

```
>UXð×?" _|_|_",Xð×?"|     |",X<U0<VXGNVXY-ð×?'+?8Y·+G'-?}'+,XY-ð×?'|?7Y·+ð×?'|,}XY-ð×?'+?8Y·+G'-?}'+,
```

Saved 14 chars thanks to Adnan! 
Definitely some room for golfing here.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=PlVYw7DDlz8iIF98X3xfIixYw7DDlz8ifCAgICAgfCIsWDxVMDxWWEdOVlhZLcOww5c_Jys_OFnCtytHJy0_fScrLFhZLcOww5c_J3w_N1nCtyvDsMOXPyd8LH1YWS3DsMOXPycrPzhZwrcrRyctP30nKyw&input=MQ)

Note that this does print everything offset by one space.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Very nice first answer :)

Comment: Maybe string multiplication helps, which is the `×` command. [This](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=J2E1w5c&input=) is an example on how it's used.

Comment: @Adnan That does help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 122 bytes

```
a='  '*input()
b='+-+'
c=d=' '
while a:b='+----'+b[1:];c=d*4+c;a=a[2:];print a+[' _|_|_',b][c>d*5]+'\n%s|%%s|'%a%c
print b
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 162 characters

```
p=print
t=int(input())
d=4*'-'
s='  '
a='+\n'
r=(t-1)*s
p(r+' _|_|_\n'+r+'|     |')
for i in range(2,t+1):b=(t-i)*s;p(b+'+-'+i*d+a+b+'| '+i*2*s+'|')
p('+-'+t*d+a)
```

It's not very clever, but I've never done one of these before. (Edit: removed unnecessary parentheses; reduced by one more character)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 73 bytes

```
+K*dtyQ"_|_|_"+tK"|     |"jP.iJms[*\ yt-Qd\+*+5*4d\-\+)+StQtQmXd"+-""| "J
```

A program that takes input of an integer on STDIN and prints the result.

There is probably still some golfing to be done here.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BK%2adtyQ%22_%7C_%7C_%22%2BtK%22%7C+++++%7C%22jP.iJms%5B%2a%5C+yt-Qd%5C%2B%2a%2B5%2a4d%5C-%5C%2B%29%2BStQtQmXd%22%2B-%22%22%7C+%22J&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&debug=0)

*Explanation coming later*

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 171 bytes

```
n=>[(s="  "[R='repeat'](n-1))+" _|_|_",s+"|     |",...Array(n-1),`+${"-"[R](n*4+1)}+`].map((_,i)=>_||(s="  "[R](n-i))+`+${"-"[R](i=i*4+1)}+`+`
${s}|${" "[R](i)}|`).join`
`
```

First pass, probably not optimal...

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>150</s> <s>147</s> <s>138</s> <s>136</s> <s>130</s> 140 bytes

new approach:

```
echo$p=str_pad("",-2+2*$n=$argv[1])," _|_|_";for($x="    ",$b=$y="----";$n--;){$a.=$x;if($n)$b.=$y;echo"
$p| $a|
",$p=substr($p,2),"+-$b+";}
```

old version for reference:

```
$p=str_pad;for($o=["_|_|_"];$i++<$n=$argv[1];$o[]="+".$p("",($i<$n)*4+$e,"-")."+")$o[]="|".$p("",$e=$i*4+1)."|";foreach($o as$s)echo$p($s,$n*4+3," ",2),"
";
```

Comment: I’m curious; how does this read input?

Comment: @Lynn: damn I forgot that this time.10 bytes overhead for `$argv`. :-/

Answer (score 1):

## Vimscript, <s>116</s> 115 bytes

Pretty messy but it works!

```
fu A(n)
let @z="Vkyjply4lpjy4hp"
exe "norm 2i+\e5i-\eo||\e5i \e".a:n."@zddl4xggd$i_|_|_"
exe "%ce ".(a:n*4+3)
endfu
```

To call it: `call A(3)` in an *empty* buffer. To load the function, `source cake.vim`

### Explanation

- `2i+<Esc>5i-<Esc>` writes the first line `+-----+`
- `o||<Esc>5i<Space><Esc>` adds `|     |` on the second line
- `Vkyjply4lpjy4hp` is saved in the macro `@z` - it visually selects both lines, yanks them, pastes them under and adds 4 dashes and spaces to them.
- `#@z` repeats this `#` times
- `ddl4x` deletes the last lines and remove for dashes to the bottom of the cake to make it equal with the top of the bottom layer
- `ggd$i_|_|_` replaces the first line by the top of the cake
- `%ce` then centers the whole cake to the  width of the bottom layer! !

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>27</s> 26 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
∫4*I:┌*╗1Ο;@*┐1Ο}⁴¹k┐╔2ΟΚ╚
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMjJCNCpJJTNBJXUyNTBDKiV1MjU1NzEldTAzOUYlM0JAKiV1MjUxMDEldTAzOUYlN0QldTIwNzQlQjlrJXUyNTEwJXUyNTU0MiV1MDM5RiV1MDM5QSV1MjU1QQ__,inputs=Mw__)

Explanation:

```
∫               }           for each in 1..input inclusive, pushing counter
 4*                           multiply by 4
   I                          increase by 1
    :                         duplicate; this will be used later
     ┌*                       repeat a dash pop times
       ╗1Ο                    encase them in plusses
          ;                   get the duplicate on the stacks top
           @*                 repeat a space pop times
             ┐1Ο              encase in vertical bars
                 ⁴          duplicate the item below ToS - the last line
                  ¹         wrap the stack in an array
                   k        remove the arrays first item
                    ┐       push "_"
                     ╔      push "|"
                      2Ο    encase 2 copies of the vertical bar in underscores
                        Κ   and prepend that to the array
                         ╚  center the array horizontally
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>139</s> <s>130</s></sub> 127 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window that takes input from cell `A1` and outputs a cake to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To[A1]:s=Space(2*([A1]-i)):x=String(1+4*i,45):?s &IIf(i=1," _|_|_","+" &x &"+"):?s"|"Replace(x,"-"," ")"|":Next:?s"+"x"+
```

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 79 bytes

```
l~4*):Z5:X{D'+'-C}:A{D'|SC}:B{X*1$N}:C];{SZX-Y/*}:D~" _|_|_"NB{XZ<}{X4+:X;AB}wA
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l~4*)%3AZ5%3AX%7BD'%2B'-C%7D%3AA%7BD'%7CSC%7D%3AB%7BX*1%24N%7D%3AC%5D%3B%7BSZX-Y%2F*%7D%3AD~%22%20_%7C_%7C_%22NB%7BXZ%3C%7D%7BX4%2B%3AX%3BAB%7DwA&input=5)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>158</s> 153 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

```c
i,l,s;p(c,s){printf("%*c%*.*s%c\n",i-~i,c,l,l,s,c);}f(n){s=memset(malloc(5*n),45,5*n);l=1;for(i=n;i--;p('|',""))l+=4,n+~i?p(43,s):p(32,"_|_|_");p(43,s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BasNADETP9lcsCyaSLRfS2JeoS3@kUIKIi2C9WbLuyXF@3VWgzOHBMMyM9D8i@64UqXAGoYJrvmtaJvBNK0371pZGvpIn7Z9KYjlLkiBvEyRcS5ivc7kuMF9ivAmMbUIaRnqRYzjydLuDhsTa99Z/eBzIe8TYhYFS99TPDMPJRs8ZTu/kvx8mj/zv8rbbFTdfNAHWa11Zm4OXpS64Ixs@ghuNXYd1VU2gSC7/LgVshett/wM)

Answer (score 0):

## QBasic, 115 bytes

```
INPUT n
?SPC(n*2-1)"_|_|_
FOR i=1TO n
s=n*2-i*2
?SPC(s)"|"SPC(i*4+1)"|
?SPC(s-2)"+"STRING$(i*4+(i=n)*4+5,45)"+
NEXT
```

#### Ungolfed

Print the top line with the candles; then print the rest of the cake two lines at a time.

```
INPUT n
PRINT SPC(n * 2 - 1); "_|_|_"
FOR i = 1 TO n
  indent = n * 2 - i * 2
  PRINT SPC(indent); "|"; SPC(i * 4 + 1); "|"
  PRINT SPC(indent - 2); "+"; STRING$(i * 4 + (i = n) * 4 + 5, 45); "+"
NEXT
```

`SPC`, when used in a `PRINT` statement, emits the given number of spaces. Conveniently, when given a negative argument, it treats it as 0, so the fact that `indent - 2` is `-2` in the last iteration isn't a problem. `STRING$` takes a count and a character code (here, 45 for `-`) and repeats the character that number of times. Here, we have to special-case the last line (when `i=n`) to be 4 hyphens shorter than it would otherwise be.